# Micro black-hole microstates

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, black-holes, entropy

If we compute the number of microstates in a black-hole of Planck radius using the Bekenstein–Hawking (BH) formula  we get $\exp(\pi/4)$. Maybe it was too optimistic to expect an integer, but regardless, I'm still puzzled by the result. Is it an artifact of the semi-classical approximation? Is there a physical interpretation for non-integer numbers of microstates?

Comment: The planck radius is only an order of magnitude thing.

Comment: That would make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two points:

1. There is no clear physical interpretation for a non-integer number of microstates.

Why not?  Because for a quantum system the space of possible states is a vector space.  When we talk about the number of microstates, we are referring to the dimensionality of that vector space (or subspace), which is an integer.

2. The entropy is not necessarily the logarithm of the number of microstates.

That's only true if the microstates are equally likely.  But in general, even though the number of microstates is an integer, the entropy is not necessarily the logarithm of an integer.